# Hi i want to convert a list of number into given format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to convert a list of number into given  format into java script
for example  the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  should be like

1:2
3:4
5:6

Comment: I'm assuming English isn't your first language. That's not necessarily a problem, but you need to demonstrate more care when formulating your question to *clearly express what you want to do*. Also, please explain where you got stuck when you attempted to do this by yourself, what happened, what went wrong? What error messages (if any) did you get? Please, if you're able, ask a friend - with more experience in the English language - to help you compose your question. And what form does this 'list of numbers' take? Is it a string? Are they in an array (of strings, or numbers)?

Answer (score -1):

supposing that the array has even number of elements
simple code:

```
var Array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var arrayLength = Array.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i+=2) {
    document.write (Array[i]+":"+Array[i+1]+"\n");
}
```

The function works as following 
First of all you define the array of elements, then you get the size of the array.
to print two numbers by two numbers I made a for loop on the array elements. in each loop the itterator increases by two. so in the first time you point the first and secound elements, then the third and fouth,,, an so.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edyt0x1w/)

Comment: where does `print()` come from? How would this work in angular view?

Comment: @charlietfl Oh, I ment to write `document.write`. thanks for notifying me. I've edited my post to show how it would work.

Comment: can't use that in an angular app...would wipe out the whole page

Comment: @charlietfl You can use getElementById("element").innerHTML instead if you want to change the inner HTML of a div.